# Prove that $f(z)=\exp\{\int_{\gamma} g(\zeta) d \zeta\}$ is holomorphic in the complement of poles of $g$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $z_n \neq 0$ and $z_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$. Suppose that $g$ is meromorphic and has a simple pole at $z_n$ with residue $k_n$. Define
\begin{equation*}
f(z)=\exp\Big\{\int_{\gamma(z)} g(\zeta) d \zeta\Big\},
\end{equation*} where $\gamma(z)$ is a path from $0$ to $z$ and it does not pass through any $z_n$. I can show that $f$ is independent of the choice of the path $\gamma(z)$. However, I can't show that $f \in H(\mathbb{C} \setminus \{z_n\})$. I have tried to start with direct derivative or Morera's Theorem, but I failed. Can anyone help?

Comment: How did you show f is independent of path? Won't the integral pickup a residue when a loop encircles $z_n$?

Comment: @Isomorphism, Yes, you are right. I should assume that $g$ has a a simple pole with residue $k_n$ at $z_n$.